# How to replace two user id columns with names?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with two columns.

created_by | assigned_to

One is the person who create a "to do card", the other column is the person who is assigned to do it.

The columns are filled with id, for example; (1,2,3).

My question is how can i replace this id with the names that are saved in another table.

by far this is what i got.

```
SELECT tickets.*, users.Name, users.LastName
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN users ON tickets.assigned_to = users.uid
AND tickets.id_usuario = users.uid
```

but when i try to print the name of the persona

Created by: `<?= query['Name']; ?>`

Assigned to: `<?= query['Name']; ?>`

but i got the same name in both columns.

Comment: Where does the `id_usuario` column come into it? You said you only have two columns, `created_by` and `assigned_to`

Comment: This table schema doesn't make much sense. What use is it to only link two users together in reference to a 3rd entity that is seemingly not referenced at all in this table? You should at least have something like a "to do card" ID in there as well. Even then, this would only make sense if you could assign multiple creators and "assigned to" users to any particular "to do card".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query only joins to `users` when the creator and assigned-to user ID are the same.

You'll need to join to your `users` table twice to retrieve the separate records. You do this by adding more joins...

```
SELECT
  c_users.Name as created_by_name,
  c_users.LastName as created_by_last_name,
  a_users.Name as assigned_to_name,
  a_users.LastName as assigned_to_last_name
FROM tickets t
INNER JOIN users c_users
  ON t.created_by = c_users.uid
  -- or t.id_usuario = c_users.uid, it is not clear from your question
INNER JOIN users a_users
  ON t.assigned_to = a_users.uid
```

I've used `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` as it doesn't seem feasible that you'd have broken relationships between the two tables.